# How do I make my own attributes (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I implemented a moveable div function in JS (moveableFunc). I used onclick="moveableFunc(event ,this)" for each div (or element) to move it. I prefer to use this function as a attribue and the code would be as follow:

```
<div id="div1" data-option="moveable" class="div1">
    hello
</div>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: do you use plain `javascript` or are you already using or plan to use a library like `jquery` ?

Comment: The implementation for moveableFunc is only by javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the `click` event in `window.onload` only for elements with that attribute, like:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var moves = document.querySelectorAll('[data-option="moveable"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
        moves[i].onclick = function (e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            moveableFunc(e, this);
        };
    }
};
```

You could even change the selector to be `.querySelectorAll('div[data-option="moveable"]');` if you know this will only be targeting `<div>`s, so it will speed up the search.

Or if you were able to restructure your `moveableFunc`'s parameters to be:

```
function moveableFunc(e) {
    // Use `this` to reference the element that was clicked
}
```

Then you could just use the following to bind the event in the loop:

```
moves[i].onclick = moveableFunc;
```

Of course, it could be preferable to use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick` to bind the events. Here's some information on that: [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener

And just as an example, with jQuery, it could be done like:

```
$('[data-option="moveable"]').on("click", moveableFunc);
```

(where you modified the parameters of `moveableFunc` like I said before)

Comment: **+1** event if i would be more strict and say it **is** preferable to use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick` because using the `on... =` always has the risk that you overwrite an already set callback somewhere else with out noticing it.

Comment: @t.niese Very true. The majority of the time, you should use `addEventListener`, but although there probably are others, there's no reason to assume there's other event handlers. Anyways, I agree, and I added a link that explains differences - it's not really necessary for me to explain it more than providing that link

Comment: I tried the 1st option (for now), and after the 2nd line, I get: moves.length=0. The html code was: <img src="Green.jpg" data-option="moveable"/>

Comment: I wrote: "window.onload = init();" in the header of index.html. init() has the code of "function" above. I found out that init() runs before the body created (firebug). Why does it happens?